# Variable Parameter in Express Route

Tags: express, routes

Is there a way to use a route in ExpressJS that uses a variable as its first parameter?

I'm trying to do something like:

`app.use('/:customer/data', component);`

And then in `component`, do:

`router.get('/:customer/manifest', function (req, res) { ... }`

I am unable to hit my route if I do it this way and was wondering if there were alternatives?

Here is an example of what my code currently looks like:

**app.js**

```
The setup before this is working correctly, so suppose we only zoom in on the route itself

// Manifest route to retrieve customer context manifest
app.use('/:customer/manifest', manifest);
```

**manifest.js**

```
router.get('/:customer/manifest', function (req, res) {
    console.log('Entering manifest route.');
});

module.exports = router;
```

I'd like for my path to be something like `/{customer}/manifest` and it go to the correct route. I tried using a Regular Expression with the aid of [the Express Route Tester](https://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/) and the expression it gave me: `/^\/(?:([^\/]+?))\/manifest\/?$/i` also did not seem to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do that, but you need to export the `router` object in your `component`:

```
router.get('/:customer/manifest', function (req, res) { ... })

// ...

module.exports = router
```

Then import and use it like you are above:

```
const express = require('express')
cont app = express()
const component = require('./component')

app.use('/:customer/data', component)
```

Comment: This makes sense to me but then I try to implement it this way, I never hit the actual route. I'm testing this locally and am trying to do something like: `http://localhost:9000/rafael/data` but I do not enter the route. I have another route defined as `/info` and this one does indeed get hit when I enter `http://localhost:9000/info`

Comment: Please post the source of your `app.js` and `component.js`

Answer (score 0):

You are adding two routes in the code, and the actual path is duped. And the actual path is :

> /:customer/manifest/:customer/manifest

You can make two different approach

**app.js**

```
app.use('/:customer/manifest', manifest);
```

**manifest.js**

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log('Entering manifest route.');
});

module.exports = router;
```

The second route should be '/' because you specify it in the previous app.use.